# Lose input focus when emitting an event Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, focus, angular5

I am using angular 5 + ngrx/store. I have own tokenfield component. That should work exactly like [bootstrap-tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/). It look something like this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqa2vc?file=app/app.component.ts). In stackblitz it works as expected, but in my app for some reasons i lose focus after every token added. It seems like `pressEnter` event trigger lose focus. 
`pressEnter` triggers an action in the container:

`addToken(token: Token) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.addToken(token));
  }`

And then i am passing to the component throw the container tokens:

`[tokens]="tokens$ | async"`

And here is the function in the reducer that handle this action:

```
export function addTokenCase(payload: Token, state: State) {
  return state.map((tokenModel) => {
    if (tokenModel.from === payload.from) {
      return {
        ...tokenModel,
        items: uniqueArray<string>([...tokenModel.items, ...payload.tokens]),
      };
    }
    return tokenModel;
  });
}
```

Where `uniqueArray` is :

```
export function uniqueArray<T>(array: T[]): T[] {
  return array.filter((elem, pos, arr) => arr.indexOf(elem) === pos);
}
```

What can be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I think we will need to see more of your original code -- seems like something might be re-rendering the input field

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the source of the problem. I had `*ngFor` above `tokenfield` component:

```
<div *ngFor="let token of tokens">
  <ui-token [token]="token"></ui-token>
</div>
```

So when i changed state with `.map()` - all `<ui-token />` components were rerendered. I added `trackBy` and it works now as expected without rerendering:

```
<div *ngFor="let token of tokens; trackBy: trackToken">
  <ui-token [token]="token"></ui-token>
</div>
```

Where `trackToken` is:

```
trackToken(index: number) {
  return index;
}
```